# gnome-shell: High-CPU usage and huge syslog

Tags: gnome, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, logging, gnome-shell

My ubuntu-gnome installation is giving me a headache... Sometimes (unfortunately I couldn't yet reproduce when) cpu-usage of the gnome-shell process hovers around 40-60% on my machine without doing anything. When that happens also the logfile is filled with entries like this:

```
Jun 28 13:33:24 tuxbook gnome-shell[1773]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55ba999fb0f0' has no handler with id '84211'
```

In other questions it seemed to be graphics related. I have tried the latest Intel drivers from 01.org but it didn't help.

Some information about my PC:

- Clevo W740SU Notebook
- Intel Core i7-4750HQ with internal graphics
- 16 GB DDR3 memory
- 1x Crucial M.2 SSD 240GB
- 1x Crucial S-SATA SSD 500GB

After a restart the problem is gone, but reappears after some time. Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause of this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to have to do with the gnome-shell extension Taskbar by ttux (there a several extensions with that name). After I have deactivated the extension and restarted the system the cpu usage didn't go up anymore and the log messages don't reappear, too!

(On a side note, if you are looking for a Windows 7 or Windows 10 like Taskbar, try the extension "Dash to Panel" - beautiful stuff)

Comment: I was experiencing same problem when I use media player extension with a media playing. Turning off seemingly fixed it